# ffmpeg ignores -metadata option when video is encoded

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, metadata, libx264

I have a video with the following metadata:

```
rotate : 90
```

I'm using ffmpeg (4.0 binaries from windows downloaded from official website) to encode it and I want to delete this metadata information.

If I do:
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate= output.mp4`
 the output will have removed the metadata.

But if I do:
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate= output.mp4`
 then I still have the undesired metadata.

Is there a way to remove metadata while encoding?

Comment: Share full log.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same issue that you're seeing and found this tracked issue: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6370

It confirms with what you're saying, the metadata field is preserved when encoding, even though you are trying to remove it.

Applying the patch to the ffmpeg build that's attached as a comment worked for me and I was able to set rotate=0, even while encoding. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/attachment/ticket/6370/0001-Fix-rotation-metadata-override-when-transcoding.patch (At least until this is fixed in a release version)

Answer (score 0):

I believe -map_metadata can help

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mp4
```